# How to use "ckeditor" with reactive-form in Angular2?

Tags: ckeditor, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I am in new in angular2. I am create a reactive form with ckeditor. all is well but my ckeditor data not post. it's null. i am read guide and create this but i am not able to get perfect result.

i m user form[formGroup] createPage and use ckditor in this form. but i can't get data of ckeditor. how can i get data from ckeditor using form. in form submit button click.

this is my ckeditor.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'CKEDITOR',
  template: `
     <textarea name="targetId" id="targetId"  rows="rows" cols="cols">
         {{content}}
     </textarea>`
})
export class AdminCkeditorComponent implements OnInit {
  content: any = "test content";
  @Input() targetId;;
  @Input() rows = 10;
  @Input() cols;     
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(){
    window['CKEDITOR']['replace']( 'targetId' );
  }
}
```

this is page.ts file

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, OnInit, Directive, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-page',
  templateUrl: './create-page.html'
})
export class CreatePageComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor (private http: Http) {}
  ngOnInit() {}
  createPage = new FormGroup({
    pageTitle: new FormControl(),
    pageUrl: new FormControl(),
    pageHeader: new FormControl(),
    pageBody: new FormControl()
  })
  public result : String;
  onSubmitPage(){
    console.log(this.createPage.value.pageTitle);
    console.log(this.createPage.value.pageUrl);
    console.log(this.createPage.value.pageHeader);
    console.log(this.createPage.value.pageBody);
      let headers = new Headers();
       headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-from-urlencoded');
       headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      let options = new RequestOptions();
      let body =this.createPage.value;
       this.http.post('http://192.168.0.130:8012/api/createPage', body, options)
       .map(res => res.json())
       .subscribe(
         data => this.result = data,
         err => console.log('ERROR!!!'+err),
         () => console.log('Got response from API', this.result)
       );
  }
}
```

this is html file

```
 <form [formGroup]="createPage" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitPage()">
       <input type="text" name="pageTitle" formControlName="pageTitle" class="form-control">
       <input type="text" name="pageUrl" formControlName="pageUrl" class="form-control" >
       <textarea name="pageHeader" formControlName="pageHeader" class="form-control"></textarea>
       <CKEDITOR></CKEDITOR> 
       <button class="btn btn-info pull-right">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Comment: have you found the solution for the same

Answer (score 7):

Why not simply:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <ckeditor [config]="config" formControlName="[YOUR_FORMCONTROL_NAME]"></ckeditor>
</form>
```

Works for me.

Comment: Can you please let me know about the validation

Answer (score 2):

I am using Angular CLI with ckeditor5 installed with NPM.

This CKEditor is inside a reactive form.

> I have **pre-made** the Input, the NgModel and the setting variable which you don't
>   see here.

*You can try and translate some of this logic to Angular 2.*

### Code:

*HTML*:

```
//...
<ckeditor [editor]="Editor" [config]="EditorConfig" (change)="change($event)" [(ngModel)]="editorData" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ckeditor>
```

*TypeScript*:

```
// ...
change({ editor }: ChangeEvent) {
  const EditorData = editor.getData();

  this.form.get('description').setValue(EditorData);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
HTML Section:
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="notification">Notification</label>
            <ckeditor [editor]="Editor" [config]="ckconfig" [formControl]="notification"  data="<p>Hello, world!</p>"></ckeditor>
        </div>


TS Section:
        //Import above
        import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

        export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
        public Editor = ClassicEditor;
        ckconfig = {
            toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote' ],
          };

        }


    notification = new FormControl('',Validators.required);
```

Just follow the way.
Reference: [Install CKEditor for angular](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html)